No such host CI, docker
Im losing my mind I'm trying to run shared gitlab runners to use them to build my docker image.  No matter what I do I always get error that no such host exists.
ERROR: error during connect: Get "http://docker:2375/v1.24/info": dial tcp: lookup docker on XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XX: no such host
errors pretty printing info

This is the GITLAB CI pipeline I wrote ( as simple as I could it's obviosuly not it's full configuration).
docker:image:
  stage: test
  image: docker:20.10  
  services:
    - docker:dind:20.10.16 
  script:
  - docker info


Shouldn’t it be docker:20.10.16-dind?

Is the service even running? Does the job’s log contain anything from starting the service?

Syntax change helped me to get it going on gitlab.com host (I was testing on gitlab host and my org host of gitlab).
But the case is I'm using gitlab on self-hosted domain (organization domain) it throws diffrent error now:
ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://docker:2375. Is the docker daemon running?

Do you have docker installed on your self hosted runner? Run sudo systemctl status docker command on your runner to ensure

I mean my organization is having their gitlab domain, so I suspect they are managing the runners? It is not possible for them to use gitlab shared runners right? I only have developer level so I cannot really see into runners. So i should probably contact them? Or is there a way I can get around this? I don't know if I understand this right.

The error above means that docker does not installed/started on the runner or improperly configured. So yes, I think you should contact them

It should be docker:20.10.16-dind, not docker:dind:20.10.16
docker:image:
  stage: test
  image: docker:20.10  
  services:
    - docker:dind:20.10.16 
  script:
  - docker info

